# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, vue-router

Whenever I load my website, I start getting some warning in console :

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for http://covid19.rohit81.com.np/js/chunk-vendors.2a297328.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have just developed my first web app using Vue & deployed in infinityfree.net. I do not get any error or warning in console when running app locally. What can I do about this warning?

Comment: That URL seems not to exist. (It redirects to a "404" page.)

Comment: I have no idea what is happening. I tried uploading this file many times. The upload gets completed but when I check the js folder, the file is not there.